# How to save uploaded file name in table using Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5.1

I need help in saving uploaded file name in database table using laravel 5.1.

My Controller code for saving Image details

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   if($request->hasFile('img_filename'))
   {
       $destinationPath="offerimages";
       $file = $request->file('img_filename');
       $filename=$file->getClientOriginalName();
       $request->file('img_filename')->move($destinationPath,$filename);

   }

    $input=$request->all();
    Offer_image::create($input);
    return redirect('offerimage');
}
```

My view code for accepting image

```
{!! Form::open(array('route'=>'offerimage.store','role'=>'form','files'=>true)) !!}
              <div class="box-body">

                <div class="form-group">
                  {!! Form::label('img_name','Name') !!}
                  {!! Form::text('img_name', $value = null, $attributes = array('class'=>'form-control','id'=>'img_name','required')) !!}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  {!! Form::label('img_description','Description') !!}
                  {!! Form::textarea('img_description', $value = null, $attributes = array('class'=>'form-control','id'=>'img_description','required')) !!}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  {!! Form::label('img_filename','Upload Image') !!}
                  {!! Form::file('img_filename') !!}
                </div>



                {!! Form::hidden('status',$value='active') !!}

              </div><!-- /.box-body -->

              <div class="box-footer">
                {!! Form::submit('Submit',$attributes=array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')) !!}
              </div>
              {!! Form::close() !!}
```

This controller code to store image working properly, but where i am trying to save image file name to table , this code is storing filepath to database table.

As I am using direct create() method to store the request object in table, I don't know how do I store file name instead of path.

[Check this Image for table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxZd5.jpg)

Comment: in my case it didn't worked because the file name database field was the same with the file input control id. After changing them the file name data flow got separated and the file name was extracted from the file input control to the corresponding field

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Problem is that your Request Data hasn't changed while you uploaded the picture. So `img_filename` still contains tmpdata.

You can try this:

```
$input = $request->all();
$input['img_filename'] = $filename;
```

Answer (score 1):

Code that works for me :

```
$updir = 'images/';
$img_name = 'image.jpeg';
Request::file('img_filename')->move($updir, $img_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = $request->file('img_filename');
$filename=$file->hashName();
```

Above is the hash name Laravel uses to save your files